# Setting up ECSlidingViewController Basic Menu Example

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I am new to IOS development. I am trying run ECSlidingViewController (2.0.3) Basic Menu Example. However, the build fails and I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lECSlidingViewController
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried `pod install` and it installed some dependencies, including ECSlidingViewController, but it still returns the error above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this: Click on your project (targets) Click on Build Settings Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths. Remove framework from your project and serach path. And after that add it again

May be this will help you

Comment: There are no values under my Library Search Paths. What do you mean by remove the framework?

Comment: When u add any library or framework you can see that framework path in your library  search path. Just remove that. And add once again your framework or library. Double click on your search path you can see all the things